# THEOS compilation errors

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-4.1, cydia

I just started playing around with THEOS and found it is good to use. But unfortunately I struck at the following errors.

```
theos/makefiles/common.mk:64: //makefiles/legacy.mk: No such file or directory
theos/makefiles/common.mk:77: *** You did not specify a target, and the "" platform does not define a default target.  Stop.
```

My makefile is

```
SDKVERSION=5.0
TARGET=iphone

TWEAK_NAME = Sample
Sample_FILES = Tweak.xm

include theos/makefiles/common.mk
include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk
```

I tried all the way that I can but no luck at this time. Anyone has a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

BTW, I'm on Snow Leopord 10.6.6 with XCode 3.2.3 (iphone sdk 4.0)

Answer (score 1):

Prefix of _FILES, _FRAMEWORKS etc must be same as TWEAK_NAME, BUNDLE_NAME, etc.

So you should change TWEAK_NAME to mytweak or prefix to Sample.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set THEOS by running the following command:

```
export THEOS=/opt/theos
```

That is if you installed theos to /opt/theos

in your makefile change

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk
```

to:

```
include $(THEOS)/makefiles/common.mk
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a layout folder and make another DEBIAN folder inside and put a control file. (Assuming you know what that is) And don't forget to chmod 0775 the folder and the control file